# DNS Suffix List not Sticking

Tags: windows-7, dns, cisco-vpn-client

I'm connecting over VPN (Cisco Anyconnect).  And what I'm doing is going to the properties of my IPv4 for that connection in Windows 7 and changing up the DNS suffix list order.  I am putting one domain in front (at the top) so that it gets priority in the list.

Works great for solving a problem I had...but the problem is, as soon as I disconnect that vpn session and re-connect...then go back to the properties of that connection and view the dns suffix list, it has defaulted back to what it was before.  So I guess there's some kind of policy or something being pushed on it.

So I can't keep that list ordered the way I need it to be.  Anyone know what is truly causing this and if there's a hack or workaround to get that to stay?

I'm talking about this DNS List:

[image]

Windows 7 | Control Panel | Networking and Sharing Center | Change Adapter Settings | Right-click my vpn connection | Properties | Click on TCP/IPv4 | Click the Properties button below | Click the Advanced button at the bottom | DNS Tab

So as you can see, I highlighted in red the domain I moved up to be the first in the list.  This solved a problem whereas we had to keep fully qualifying all resources on that domain so moving this up got rid of that problem and allowed the 2nd domain to still function normal as usual.

Comment: What is the suffix when you right click on Start>Computer>Properties>Full Computer Name? It is the one that always ends up at the top? Are you getting your DNS settings on your General tab from DHCP?

Comment: This is the same question, and the same questioner, as ["DNS Suffix order does not stick"](http://superuser.com/questions/294323/).

Comment: the suffix is the one I moved to the top when I look at the computer properties but that is not the one that ends up at the top.  My PC is a member of that domain I move to the top but the one that's always being added in at the top of this vpn connection is another domain because we were bought out by another company (their domain is what we use vpn over) but there are still resources...many that we use on the domain I'm trying to keep at the top.

Comment: yes I'm using DHCP